# C# Generics: Can I use them in this example?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0

How can I do this with generics?

In my current code, I am writing something like this for each feature on a vehicle.

```
        foreach (var vaudioSystem in VehicleAudioSystem)
        {
            var acMl = (VOVehicleFeatureList) FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof (VOVehicleFeatureList));
            acMl.IsInitialized = false;
            acMl.Initialize(true);
            acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.AudioSystem;
            acMl.ValueId = vaudioSystem;
                vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
        }
        foreach(var axle in VehicleAxles)
        {
            var acMl =
                (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
            acMl.IsInitialized = false;
            acMl.Initialize(true);
            acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Axles;
            acMl.ValueId = axle;
            vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
        }
        foreach(var nav in VehicleNavSystem)
        {
            var acMl =
                (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
            acMl.IsInitialized = false;
            acMl.Initialize(true);
            acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.NavSystem;
            acMl.ValueId = nav;
            vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
            }
```

Is there someway I can reduce the length of this code using Generics or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Do VehicleAudioSystem, VehicleAxles and VehicleNavSystem derive from a common base class?

Comment: VehicleAudioSystem / VehicleAxles and VehicleNavSystem are collections created by me. They are lists of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply write a method which adds the vehicle features to your vehiclespec

```
public void AddVehiculeFeatures(IEnumerable<int> featureList, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType listType, Vehicle vehicleSpec)
{
 foreach(int feature in featureList)
 {
  var acMl = (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));             
  acMl.IsInitialized = false;             
  acMl.Initialize(true);             
  acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = listType;            
  acMl.ValueId = nav;             
  vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);             

 }
}
```

and usage:

```
AddVehiculeFeatures(axesList, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Axes, vehicleSpec)
AddVehiculeFeatures(otherList, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Other, vehicleSpec)
AddVehiculeFeatures(thirdFeatureList, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.third one, vehicleSpec)
```

Comment: I am trying this out now. Thx for the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function which takes your list and the enum value then call it three times.

```
protected void AddFeaturesFromlist(List<int> featureList, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType type)
{
    foreach(var item in featureList)
    {
        var acMl =(VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
        acMl.IsInitialized = false;
        acMl.Initialize(true);
        acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = type;
        acMl.ValueId = item;
        vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
    }
}

AddFeaturesFromlist(VehicleAudioSystem, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.AudioSystem);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not generics, but you can certainly make it more elegant with a little bit of method refactoring. You are repeating a lot of code, so try to reduce that.

```
    foreach (var vaudioSystem in VehicleAudioSystem)
        AddFeature(vaudioSystem, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.AudioSystem);

    foreach(var axle in VehicleAxles)
        AddFeature(axle, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Axles);

    foreach(var nav in VehicleNavSystem)
        AddFeature(nav, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.NavSystem);

[...]

public static void AddFeature(int id, VehicleFeatureListType type)
{
    var acMl = (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(
        typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
    acMl.IsInitialized = false;
    acMl.Initialize(true);
    acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = type;
    acMl.ValueId = id;
    vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really want to* use generics, here’s a version that uses LINQ :)

```
foreach (var item in
    VehicleAudioSystem.Select(id => new { id, type = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.AudioSystem }).Concat(
    VehicleAxles.Select(id => new { id, type = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Axles }).Concat(
    VehicleNavSystem.Select(id => new { id, type = GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.NavSystem }))))
{
    var acMl = (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
    acMl.IsInitialized = false;
    acMl.Initialize(true);
    acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = item.type;
    acMl.ValueId = item.v;
    vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);
}
```

Comment: @fantasticfix: Well, it doesn't use generics but it accomplishes the same thing, eliminating repetition of the same code.

Comment: i dont say it doesnt work --> but with the title "If you really want to use generics..." i have to say. NO, IT DOESNT USE GENERICS ;-)

Comment: @fantasticfix: It doesn’t *declare* any generic types or methods, but it certainly *uses* them (`Select` and `Concat`).

Answer (score 0):

**Generic Solution:**

First, make a class named VehicleFeature as follows:

```
public class VehicleFeature
{
    public int ValueId;
    public GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType VehicleFeatureListType;
    public VehicleFeature(int valueId, GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType vehicleFeatureListType)
    {
        this.ValueId = valueId;
        this.VehicleFeatureListType = vehicleFeatureListType;
    }
}
```

Then, create a Class named VehicleFeatureList that inherits of List:

```
public class VehicleFeatureList : List<VehicleFeature>
{
    public GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType VehicleFeatureListType { get; set; }

    private List<VehicleFeature> values;

    public List<VehicleFeature> Values
    {
        get { return values; }
        set { values = value; }
    }

    public void Add(int ValueId)
    {
        this.values.Add(new VehicleFeature(ValueId, this.VehicleFeatureListType));
    }

    public void AddRange(int[] values)
    {
        foreach (int item in values)
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public VehicleFeatureList(GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType vehicleFeatureListType)
    {
        this.VehicleFeatureListType = vehicleFeatureListType;
    }
}
```

Next, your variables "VehicleAudioSystem", "VehicleAxles" and "VehicleNavSystem" won't be List but just of the type VehicleFeatureList. Don't forget to put the correct type of feature everytime:

```
        VehicleFeatureList VehicleAudioSystem = new VehicleFeatureList(GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.AudioSystem);
        VehicleFeatureList VehicleAxles = new VehicleFeatureList(GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.Axles);
        VehicleFeatureList VehicleNavSystem = new VehicleFeatureList(GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType.NavSystem);
```

You can add a value to your variable like that:

```
        VehicleAxles.Add(5);
```

If you want to add various values at the same type, you can do :

```
        VehicleAudioSystem.AddRange(new int[] {1,5,6,9});
```

And then, you have this unique function working for any feature you want:

```
    private void AddToVehicleFeatureList<T>(T VehicleParameterType)
        where T : VehicleFeatureList
    {
        foreach (var item in VehicleParameterType)
        {
            var acMl =
           (VOVehicleFeatureList)FrameworkFactoryApi.CreateVO(typeof(VOVehicleFeatureList));
            acMl.IsInitialized = false;
            acMl.Initialize(true);
            acMl.VehicleFeatureListType = item.VehicleFeatureListType;
            acMl.ValueId = item.ValueId;
            vehicleSpec.VehicleFeatureLists.Add(acMl);        
        }
    }
```

You call the method like that:

```
        AddToVehicleFeatureList(VehicleAudioSystem);
```

You can add any feature type you want in your GlobalEnums.VehicleFeatureListType, the code will still work.
Greetings

Comment: Hello Thanks for replying. I have used the solution suggested by fantasticfix

Comment: Hello, you're welcome. His solution is indeed a good one and is much faster to use than mine.